# Kotlin Data Class Parsing Mutiple member properties at once

Tags: kotlin

Let say I have a data class called Class A

```
data class ClassA {
 val x0 = ""
 val x1 = "some string"
 val x2 = "some string"
 val x3 = "some string"
 val x4 = "some string"
 val x5 = ""
 val x6 = ""
 val y = ""
 val z = ""
}
```

I can retrieve the value of these class member thru its class object

```
val obj = ClassA()
// if the properties has prefix x and not empty then concatenate to this x variable
val x = obj.x1 + obj.x2 + etc...
...
```

Let say if this data class has 50+ x(n) in it and I want to retrieve any member that does not have an "empty string or null" and match the prefix then how do I do it dynamically (can be a for-loop), instead of type out statically every single properties that I want to retrieve, is there an alternative way to do it?

Comment: This can be done with reflection, but in any practical case, you would use a Collection, Map or Array instead of many similar properties.

Comment: I second @Tenfour04's comment, trying to solve this problem with reflection is a code smell to me. Using a collection of some sort reduces the number of issues that can arise when using reflection. Reflection is a powerful tool, but it really shouldn't be used unless absolutely required.

Comment: Thirded. Reflection is needed for things like frameworks, plugins, and build tools; but it's slow, fragile, insecure, ugly, long-winded, and in general application code there's nearly always a better approach. — In this cast a list-based approach seems the obvious place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve that with Reflection:

```
data class ClassA (
  val x0: String = "",
  val x1: String = "some string 1",
  val x2: String = "some string 2",
  val x3: String = "some string 3",
  val x4: String = "some string 4",
  val x5: String = "",
  val x6: String = "",
  val y: String = "",
  val z: String = ""
)

val obj = ClassA()

val result = ClassA::class.java.declaredFields   // or: 
  .filter { it.name.startsWith("x") }
  .onEach { it.isAccessible = true }
  .map { it.get(obj) }
  .joinToString("; ")


println(result)
```

This will print:

```
; some string 1; some string 2; some string 3; some string 4; ;
```

If you want to omit x0, x5, and x6, which all are empty strings, and you want to concatenate without semicolon:

```
val result = Class::class.java.declaredFields
  .filter { it.name.startsWith("x") }
  .onEach { it.isAccessible = true }
  .map { it.get(obj) }
  .filter { it != "" }
  .joinToString("")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer you question and provide a way of doing it, however, I highly recommend against doing it this way simply because while it works, it is seen as hacky and you'd be better off solving this by changing the multiple fields/properties into a collection of some sort instead.

You can use reflection to do it without having to type out all of the values manually.

To do it via [reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html), you will have to do something like this.

```
fun getNonEmptyStrings(input: A): List<String> {
    val members = A::class.memberProperties

    return members
        .filter { it.name.startsWith("x") }
        .map { it.get(input) }
        .filterIsInstance<String>()
        .filter { it.isNotBlank() }
}
```

There might be some other form of meta-programming that is better suited to this, but I'm not sure what that would be.